# How to view HTML content of sent email in sendgrid?

Tags: email, sendgrid, mandrill, email-templates

How to view content of email which is sent for particular recipient in Sendgrid? Mandrill for instance has a dashboard where you can open any email which was sent by your service. I need it to be able to test if dynamic data is correctly rendered on the email template

I checked their docs and found only dashboard with statuses and emails of recipients but not with actual email content